# Bitnodes check on .onion addr returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: bitcoin-core, tor, bitnodes

Question on inbound connections. I am running via tor proxy and getting outbound connections. Node is running in pruned mode and is up to date. I manually created hidden service via torrc config file. When checking the node via bitnodes i am seeing HTTP403 forbidden. In earlier tests I was getting unreachable so seems like some sort of progress. Tor and btc core are running in the same docker container. Any thoughts on the cause of the 403? I have no port changes in my router as I am under the impression for tor and onion i dont need to do port forwarding. Thanks.

bitcoin.conf

```
prune=5000
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
torcontrol=none
onlynet=onion
maxuploadtarget=2000
listen=1
listenonion=1
bind=127.0.0.1
externalip=XXXXX.onion
debug=tor
debug=http
debug=proxy
shrinkdebugfile=1
```

torrc changes:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/bitcoin-service/
HiddenServicePort 8333 127.0.0.1:8334
```

Comment: The Bitcoin P2P protocol is not HTTP based; 403 is an HTTP error. Whatever you're seeing, I doubt it has anything to do with your node.

Comment: Thanks. I refreshed the bitnodes website and the node was reachable again. Guess I had timed out on bitnodes...ugh